# While Loop Counter Confusion

Tags: python, while-loop, counter, nested-loops, break

I'm working with while loops and I'm just a bit confused on how to break out of it in the way that I want. So I've nested a for loop within a while loop:

```
x = True
y = 0
while x:
  if y >= 5:
    x = False
    print('break')
  else:
      for x in range(7):
        y += 1 
        print('test')
```

The output that I'm looking for is 5 tests printed out and one break. However, every time I run the program it prints out 7 tests before it goes to the break. I'm not exactly sure, but I think I'm just confused about something within while loops! If someone could explain this to me please let me know :) I have found ways around this, but I'd like to get an understanding of why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason 7 `test`s print rather than 5 is that your entire `for` loop is executed before you go back to the beginning of your `while` statement. I think your understanding is that, after one iteration of a `for` loop, you go back to the beginning of the `while` loop, but this is incorrect: your `for` loop is executed completely before going back to the beginning of the `while` loop.

After you step into the `for` loop, you increment `y` 7 times and print `test` 7 times. `y` is now >= 5, and you go back into your `if` statement. The `if` statement turns `x` false, thereby "turning off" the `while` loop, and a `break` statement is printed. If you just want to print out 5 `test`s and one `break`, it would be much easier to simplify your code as such:

```
y = 0
while True:
    if y < 5:
        print('test')
        y += 1
    else:
        print('break')
        break
```

Comment: Thank you this explanation was very clear and I can understand it a lot better now! really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

This is because it's performing the entire for loop within the while loop therefore y will become 7 before it checks again. Removing the for loop will resolve this.

```
x = True
y = 0
while x:
  if y >= 5:
    x = False
    print('break')
  else:
    y += 1 
    print('test')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
y = 0
while y < 5:
  print("test")
  y += 1
print("break")
```

Would work.

There is no point in having another variable like "x" for the while loop when it allows for you to set the condition directly.

Answer (score 1):

Because inner loop will complete before the next iteration of the outer loop. I.e. once the inner loop starts it does all 7 iterations before starting the next iteration of the while loop.

You can do this by just using one loop. Print out “test” increase counter and put in an if condition to break when counter is 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
i = 0
while True:
    if i == 5:
        break
    print('test')
    i = i + 1
```